# Change apache2 php path

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I am using https://github.com/wilmoore/php-version to switch between php versions on my local machine, installed within `~/php/versions`. Currently setting up separate VMs with different versions of php installed is not an option.

When I switch php version through the command line using the linked tool, I see it listed as php 7. This also works when using `php -v`. I have restarted terminal and the machine and it still says php 7.

I have updated `composer.json` to require php 7.0.2 and greater. Yet when I use `phpinfo()` in my laravel application, it always states the default `PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14`.

Where is laravel pointing to the php distribution in my Ubuntu 14.04.3 machine and where can I change this path?

**EDIT:** I am using Apache. I can see in the `phpinfo()` output that it is reading the `ini` file from `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`. I have looked in this file but cannot see where to point to the php distribution.

Comment: What HTTP server are you using?

Comment: @Bogdan Just updated the question for you.

Comment: The command line version of PHP will be a different version to the PHP module your installed web server (Apache) uses. You’ll need to update the PHP module.

Comment: @MartinBean Yes I understand this now, but how do I update the PHP module?

Comment: Look into fcgi, it's usually the way to accomplish what you are trying to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache loads the php5_module library in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.load`.

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
```

If you know the loactions of your alternative libraries you can change them in this file.

After editing you need to restart your apache. `sudo service apache2 restart` or `sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`

Comment: Is it possible to create a `php7_module` file and point that to the equivalent php7 version of `libphp5.so`? If so, how can I get apache to choose that over `php5.load`?

Answer (score 2):

first make sure that `php7.*.conf` and `php7.*.load` files are exist in `/etc/apache2/mods-available` directory.

then use `sudo a2enmod php7.*` to enable the mod

use `sudo a2dismod php5.*` to disable the mod

after running the two commands restart your apache2 server

using `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue on ubuntu16.

```
ls -l /etc/apache2/mods-available/php7* , 
showed 2 versions - 
/etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.0.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.2.conf
```

Deleted the `/etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.0.conf`, restarted apache2, and `phpinfo()` via apache2 showed php7.2